# Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform even though there is a field 'name' in firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im tryig to implement search page for the products in firestore. But when im trying to list products' names in upper case, it gives an error

> The following StateError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#059ea):
> Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform"

if i try to list products' names in lower case, it does not throw an error but also it does not work.

Note: There is a field 'name' in firestore, so i did not understand what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SearchScreen> createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  String searchInput = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: CupertinoSearchTextField(
          autofocus: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          onChanged: (value){
            setState((){
              searchInput = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return const Material(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
          final result = snapshot.data!.docs.where(
                  (e) => e['name'.toLowerCase()]
                      .contains(searchInput.toLowerCase()),
          );
          return ListView(
            children: result.map((e) => Text(e['name'.toUpperCase()])).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
e.get('name').toString().toLowerCase();
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final result = snapshot.data!.docs.where(
              (e) => e['name'].toLowerCase()
                  .contains(searchInput.toLowerCase()),);
result.map((e) => Text(e['name'].toUpperCase())).toList(),
```